# Geometry. How to solve this problem?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

In triangle $ABC$, $P$ and $Q$ are points on $AB$ and $AC$ respectively such that $AP:PB=8:1$ and $AQ:QC=15:1$. $X$ and $Y$ are points on $BC$ such that the circumcircle of triangle $APX$ is tangent to both $BC$ and $CA$, while the circumcircle of triangle $AQY$ is tangent to both $AB$ and $BC$.

How to find $\cos\widehat{BAC}$?

[image]

Comment: Use https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference to properly format equations.

Comment: What is Mathjax? How to use it?

Comment: @RayCheng: I have improved formatting (have a look at the code), but you still need to add you attempts.

Comment: Thanks, @Jack D'Aurizio for this nice figure. I imagine as you have built point I because it  contributes to a solution ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: it can be used, of course. If the OP is confident with trilinear or barycentric coordinates, the previous lines provide a clear path to the solution.

Comment: I am a new user. Thank you for your kind support!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my solution again but in a neater way
[image]

Comment: this is the graph https://ggbm.at/kwxDWQnT

Answer (score 2):

Let $O_C$ be the center of the circumcircle of $APX$ and $O_B$ be the center of the circumcircle of $AQY$.

$O_C$ has to lie on three different lines: the perpendicular to $CA$ through $A$, the angle bisector of $\widehat{ACB}$ and the perpendicular bisector of $AP$. Similarly, $O_B$ has to lie on the perpendicular to $BA$ through $A$, on the angle bisector of $\widehat{CBA}$ and on the perpendicular bisector of $AQ$.

Since $O_C$ lies on a angle bisector and on a perpendicular, $O_C A$ is given by $b\tan\frac{C}{2}$.
Since $O_C$ lies on the perpendicular bisector of $AP$, we also have $O_C A\sin A=\frac{4}{9}c$.

A similar argument for $O_B$ leads to $O_B A = c\tan\frac{B}{2}$ and $O_B A\sin A=\frac{15}{32}b$. Summarizing:

$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}b \tan\frac{C}{2}&=&\frac{4c}{9\sin A}\\c\tan\frac{B}{2}&=&\frac{15b}{32\sin A} \end{array}\right. $$
that can be written as 
$$\left\{\begin{array}{rcl}\frac{br}{a+b-c}&=&\frac{4c R}{9a}\\
\frac{cr}{a+c-b}&=&\frac{15b R}{32 a} \end{array}\right. $$
implying
$$ c^2=18\cdot\frac{\Delta^2}{(a+b)^2-c^2},\qquad b^2=\frac{256}{15}\cdot\frac{\Delta^2}{(a+c)^2-b^2} $$
and 
$$ c^2=\frac{9}{8}(a-b+c)(-a+b+c),\qquad b^2=\frac{16}{15}(-a+b+c)(a+b-c) $$
due to Heron's formula. This implies
$$ (a,b,c)=\lambda\cdot (13,8,15) $$
and

> $$ \cos\widehat{BAC} = \frac{b^2+c^2-a^2}{2bc} = \color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}. $$

$\widehat{B}$ is not a right angle but it is quite close to a right angle, since $8^2+13^2=15^2+8$.

Comment: How to find b/c

Comment: also is angle B a right angle?

Comment: In order to find the b/c ratio you just to divide the last two equations term by term and solve a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: divide what by what?

Comment: How to show a quadratic polynomial?

Comment: @RayCheng: I included a complete derivation, the involved computations need to be checked but the approach should be clear now.

Comment: why sin A =a/R and why tan(C/2)=r/(a+b-c)

Comment: what is r and R

Comment: @RayCheng: $r$ is the inradius and $R$ is the circumradius. A suggestion: before tackling difficult geometry problems, try to learn the basics. First things first: try to prove that $a=2R\sin A$ and $\tan(C/2)=\frac{2r}{a+b-c}$ by yourself.

Comment: a=2R sin A comes from Inscribed Angle Theorem https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Law_of_Sines

Comment: tan(C/2)=2r/(a+b-c) comes from the law of cotangents. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cotangents

Comment: what is delta??

Comment: $\Delta$ is the area of $ABC$, i.e. $\frac{abc}{4R}$ or $\sqrt{p(p-a)(p-b)(p-c)}$.

Comment: c^2=\frac{9}{8}(a-b+c)(-a+b+c),\qquad b^2=\frac{16}{15}(-a+b+c)(a+b-c) How can I find this by Heron's formula as you mentioned above?

Comment: delta squared should be (a+b+c)(−a+b+c)(a−b+c)(a+b−c)/16 , isn't it?

Comment: @RayCheng: correct.

Comment: I find that a=11,b=8,c=9. Using cosine formula, cos angle BAC =1/6, but my value of a , b, c are different from yours. So, is it contain more than one triangle ?

Comment: Perhaps there is more than one solution, but honestly I spent enough time on this problem and I prefer to disengage.

Answer (score 0):

@Jack D'Aurizio:
The correct answer should be 1/6 but not 1/2, and this is the solution given by The Hong Kong Academy for Gifted Education (HKAGE).
[image]